# Service exited due to SIGABRT, Thread 30

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-background-downloader for my react native project. There is a button on which when I click, download starts in Documents.dir(RNFetchBlob). This is the behavior in Android OS. But in iOS, as soon as I click the download button. The app crashes.
I think it is something about the url scheme. I changed the url to a hardcoded url like a play store apk, and it worked. But the url which I used to(want to) pass (which index url) turns out to crash my application

##Complete log:-

```
SLink_ios[11757:276497] Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: (null). Valid schemes are http or https 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.940985+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276497] Task <81F6DEDF-F785-48FA-979C-5C21382B3D14>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=( "BackgroundDownloadTask <81F6DEDF-F785-48FA-979C-5C21382B3D14>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDownloadTask <81F6DEDF-F785-48FA-979C-5C21382B3D14>.<1>} [-1002] 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.943 [info][tid:main][RCTImageView.m:422] Reloading image http://localhost:8081/assets/src/Assets/download.png?platform=ios&hash=9dde24daa36aede3432b0ac881695f75 as size {36, 36} 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.942703+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276357] Reloading image http://localhost:8081/assets/src/Assets/download.png?platform=ios&hash=9dde24daa36aede3432b0ac881695f75 as size {36, 36} 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.943100+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276473] Task .<368> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/assets/src/Assets/spinner.gif?platform=ios&hash=2f2ad9512c7ad4ea794d3a5d6adbd69e, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/assets/src/Assets/spinner.gif?platform=ios&hash=2f2ad9512c7ad4ea794d3a5d6adbd69e, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=( "LocalDataTask .<368>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<368>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999] 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.943343+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276432] Task .<368> finished with error - code: -999 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.954 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] unsupported URL 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.954103+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276480] unsupported URL 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.980064+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276357] To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ]; 
2019-01-29 00:48:35.999636+0530 SLink_ios[11757:276497] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:]: key cannot be nil' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e93b1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010dd34735 objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e8874ec _CFThrowFormattedException + 194 3 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e9acd45 -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:] + 213 4 SLink_ios 0x0000000107f1cffc -[RNBackgroundDownloader removeTaskFromMap:] + 268 5 SLink_ios 0x0000000107f1ffdc -[RNBackgroundDownloader URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] + 572 6 CFNetwork 0x0000000109952342 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.241 + 284 7 Foundation 0x000000010ae07f9e __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 7 8 Foundation 0x000000010ae07ea5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68 9 Foundation 0x000000010ae04c14 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 689 10 Foundation 0x000000010ae0ac4b __NSOQSchedule_f + 227 11 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa41595 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 12 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa42602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 13 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa4554d _dispatch_continuation_pop + 565 14 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa44927 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 859 15 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa5300a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 351 16 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000010fa539af _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 130 17 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000010fe266dd _pthread_wqthread + 619 18 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000010fe26405 start_wqthread + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) `
```

I do not know which files/screenshots will be required to answer this question. I am uploading those which I think will be enough. If any other information is needed, I am happy to provide.

Here are the required files:-
[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wuWpnYOJy67jsrqYLSR23J9MiA9yQGA_?usp=sharing)

I tried the following things:

1. Cleaned and rebuild the project.
2. Erased All Content and Settings of Simulator.

[image: Redirected here, on clicking download button]
[image: LOGS]

Comment: Have you carefully followed the documentation, especially in regard to [the extra step for iOS](https://github.com/EkoLabs/react-native-background-downloader#ios---extra-mandatory-step)?

Comment: Yes I have. I guess I might have figured out. The problem is with the url. I changed the url and it works.  
"Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: (null). Valid schemes are http or https 2019-01-29 00:48:35.940985+0530 SLink_ios"

Comment: Please use the help centre to find out how to format questions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding the url worked for me :) encodeURI(url)

Comment: Before fetching the url (i.e. before doing fetch(url)). Sorry for late response